# Comment System using Redis Database System

Tags: comments, redis

I am trying to build a comment system using Redis database, I am currently using hashes to store the comment data, but the problem I am facing is that after 10 or 12 comments, comments lose their order and start appearing randomly, anyone know what data type should be used for building a commenting system using Redis, currently my hashes are of the form.

postid:comments commentid:userid "Testcomment"

Thanks, Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashes are set up for quick access by key rather than retrieval in order. If you need items in a particular order, try a list or sorted set.

The reason it appears to work at first is an optimization for small sets - when you only have a small number of items a list is the most efficient structure, so that is what redis uses internally. When you get more items, an actual hashmap is needed for efficient querying and redis rearranges the data so that it is ordered by hash rather than by insertion order.

Comment: Sorted lists really helped me

Comment: You said hashes are setup for quick access, so if I use sorted lists should I expect decrease in speed?

Comment: That's quick access by key - if you know the key you can retrieve any single item very fast, but you don't know what the first item is. With lists you can get the first or last items in constant time, but getting an item from somewhere in the middle of a million item list will be very slow.

Comment: So if I have created a system where I store comments against a post in a sorted list and retrieve it by post id stored in lets say mysql, do I still experience decrease in performance? Because I am retrieving whole list not an item from start, end or middle?

Comment: No, performance will be the same in this scenario - the difference is that it will actually give the results you are looking for. In any case, if you are just using redis to get IDs for a SQL query, redis will definitely not be the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

With my web app, I am using a format like this.

```
(appname):(postid):(comment id) - The hash of the posts
(appname):(postid):count - The latest comment id
```

And then I query the (appname):(postid):count key to get the amount of times I should run a loop that gets the contents of the (appname):(postid):(comment id) hash.

Example Code

```
$c = $redis->get('(appname):(postid):count');
for($i = 0; $i<$c; $i++) {
    var_dump($redis->hgetall('(appname):(postid):'.$i));
}
```